# Defining CSS for Dojo textbox

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

I have a **Dojo** textbox with inline styling however i would like to define styling in an external css file for the item. I would like to know what class can be used to define styling for Dojo input="text" elements alone.

I have tried using DijitReset and DijitInputInner classes however this is not specific to text items only. Under is an example of the tag i am working with.

```
<input id="ltb" style="width: 50em;" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" />
```

I am not comfortable with having inline css for tags since i have always know it to be a bad practice when doing modular development (your thoughts on this as well. seeing this is specific to **Dojo** framework)

Comment: Can you *devtools/inspect* the element dojo creates to look at the classes dojo adds ?

Comment: I'm taking it that `#ltb { width:50em; }` in a css file does not work ?

Comment: @RobSedgwick no that does not work

Comment: @RobSedgwick the classes it uses are DijitReset and DijitInputInner and these are used for buttons as well so the css defined affects buttons

Comment: hmm okay ( sorry Im not that up on dojo ) - how about wrapping the element in a span `<span class="stylemegoddammit"><input ..`   `.stylemegoddammit input { ` ( from what I can see of the dojo docs - http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/TextBox.html - they promotes the use of inline style to build it's dojo input ) ergghh

Comment: Yes i am seeing they are promoting inline styling which i am not liking right now. I could try the span tag as you said. Will let you know how that goes shortly

Comment: Wrapping it in a span tag did not affect the width of the textbox :(

Comment: Have you included the "dojo/parser" in the require array?  That may be needed to get the example you gave to work.

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at Dojo and how it does it styles

The reason for Dojo **[explicity saying use inline style](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/TextBox.html)** is ( perhaps) because the classes they add are full of '!importants' ( *now I say 'they' - this might just be what is in the default clara theme* ) || some dojo javascript is looking for it

```
.dijitInputInner {
   border: 0 !important;
   vertical-align: middle !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
   width: 100% !important;
   padding-left: 0 !important;
   padding-right: 0 !important;
   margin-left: 0 !important;
   margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

**[I had a play here](http://jsfiddle.net/PYe6x/)** - and, through the inpsect tools in chrome , it showed that in fact the `id` on the input stayed put, so we **could** use it ...

```
#ltb { width:50em; }
/* but we need to overide it */
#ltb.dijitReset, #ltb.dijitInputInner { width:5em !important; }
```

---

From the [trials](http://jsfiddle.net/PYe6x/) we can see that we are also going to be battling with the CSS for the dojo containers , that are set as `overlow:hidden` etc.

---

I don't know the reason for the `clara` stylesheet using importants ( *I'm taking it that is the default dojo theme* ) - but the answer to the inline styling question is either

- use the inline style ( don't fight with dojo )
- or change the dojo theme file itself
- Or create our own css overides using `!important`
- or something I am missing from the docs in my very limited experience of dojo

Comment: *just some investigation that was too large for a comment - if you would like me to remove this after having a look, so that the answer remains 'unanswered', let me know

Comment: its great i will not accept it as an answer just yet i would like some more feed back from others however i may just eventually accept it since its a great investigation